# WPF: Why does passing in random types to DependencyProperty methods work fine?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

WPF newbie here. I was just experimenting with `DependencyProperty` a bit and was surprised to see this code runs fine without throwing an exception:

```
var prop = DependencyProperty.Register("Blah", typeof(int), typeof(int));
prop.AddOwner(typeof(string));
```

Obviously, neither `int` or `string` inherit from `DependencyObject`. Why, then, are they allowed to be passed in to `Register`/`AddOwner`? What is it possible to use the returned `DependencyProperty` for?

Thanks.

(This question is also tagged as [windows-runtime], since WinRT exposes some of these APIs as well.)

Comment: Take a look at [attached properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.100).aspx). Their "owner type" does not need to be a DependencyObject.

Comment: @Clemens Yes, but I'm using `Register` and not `RegisterAttached` here and it still seems to be working.